# Why are the leaves of my potted aloe vera plant turning yellow and getting tiny dark spots?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, watering, aloe

I have noticed that some of the tips are yellowing and curving downward. Also, these very same leaves are becoming flatter and have a lot of tiny dark spots.
[image]

Is the issue over or underwatering? The plant gets plenty of sun.
Thank you.